# sudden Server Certificate verification failure

Tags: git, ssl, ssl-certificate

It seems my search queries don't help me at all on google or here on stack overflow.
So now I turn to you guys and I hope you can help me past this problem.

Here is the situation.

We have a Ubuntu Webserver that runs multiple websites.
The server has git and it is installed and fully working.
That is until this afternoon.

Suddenly whenever I did a pull request from the server I got the following error

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.example.com/websites/EUclaimde.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

When going to our git server it only says it is a self signed certificate and i can continue just fine to the page.

The strange (or maybe it's not strange at all) thing is that the other website work just fine.
It is only one site that gives this error.

Note: I did not change any settings nor did others working on the project nor did we change any other system files.

When I go to the folder that is indicated in the error message the certificate is there.
Probably also the reason why ther pages still work.

If you nee any other info please let me know and I will update the question.

THank you for your time.

Cheers

Comment: Visit [git.lennoc.com](https://git.lennoc.com) in your browser. Does it give you a more specific error, like the certificate has expired?

Comment: @DanLowe I don't get any errors.
Just that it's a self signed certificate and when I click on the link to go on to the git page it all works like a charm.

It is specifically from the server and that one page that has the problem.

Comment: Then the problem is that it's a self-signed certificate. Those generally fail verification checks because there is no upstream trusted signer.

Comment: Well I can understand that that could be the problem but can such things just ... happen... ? cause up till 12:30 pm (give or take) it worked and i did multiple pull requests but suddenly after that i got this error

Comment: It's not possible for us here as outsiders to tell you that... the most likely explanation is that something happened on the server, either automatically or due to human intervention, that caused the certificate to change from what was there before, to this one. Only your server admins can tell you why that happened (or fix it).

Comment: hmm ok thanks for the info. at least you confirmed part of my suspicions.