# Unable to correct sudden "server certificate verification failed"

Tags: git, ssl, raspberry-pi, ssl-certificate, gitlab

I have the following problem:

- I have two machines here, a PC (Windows) and a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian).
- I have a git repo on gitlab.com, using an https URL.
- On the PC, I have been using and continue to use git (command line, git shell) with zero issues.
- On the Pi, today I can no longer access the repo, `git pull origin master`, for example, fails with:

  ```
    server certificate verification failed
  ```

  This is a new issue. I had been happily using git on that devices for months, and  nothing was touched on it since the last time I  used it successfully about a week or so ago (the device hasn't even been powered on since).

Not knowing much about SSL and certificates, I've just been hunting for solutions and blindly executing commands with no success. So far all I've found and tried is:

- [github: server certificate verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821245/github-server-certificate-verification-failed) - Seems the most promising. I went through the accepted answer there, updated ca-certificates on the device, manually installed the root certificates, and made sure git was using them, but the error persisted. The OP mentioned "I just added the downloaded cacert.org CAs to my trusted.pem, and now git doesn't complain anymore" but I do not understand how to do this.
- [Git Clone Fails: Server Certificate Verification Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444154/git-clone-fails-server-certificate-verification-failed) - The suggested solution here is simply to disable SSL verification, which I don't really understand since it's always worked up until now. Anyways I tried it and, for reasons I do not understand, after git prompted me for a username and password it said "Basic Authentication Failed". I am 100% sure that I entered the correct username and password.
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cannot-clone-via-https-with-error-server-certificate-verification-failed/4782 doesn't seem to apply as it is talking about the server side? My repo is hosted at gitlab.com, I don't run the server. In any case the solution there mentions something about adding a newline somewhere but I don't understand where or how that type of problem could suddenly have developed.
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865952 seems Ubuntu-specific and the solution doesn't seem related to my situation.
- [sudden Server Certificate verification failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876091/sudden-server-certificate-verification-failure) also appears to be related to an in-house git server.
- [Playing with my cat for 5 minutes and trying again](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5827765#5827765) - This does not seem to be working.

It doesn't make sense to me that it would be a server screw-up on the GitLab side, given that my PC continues to access the repo just fine. I'm also not having any issues on their site, their [status Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/gitlabstatus) doesn't mention anything, and also it seems odd that they would screw this particular thing up (plus the problem has been going on all day now).

I'm not sure what to try next. What's my next step here? It's a bit frustrating as it's frozen project development all day so far.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, the system clock had been reset... correcting the time (and setting up NTP to avoid it in the future) solved the issue.

I did not find [server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c) in my searching, it was pointed out to me [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5827796#5827796), and one of the suggestions was to [check the clock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945443/616460).

I am therefore going to close this question as a duplicate of that one, but if anybody finds this in the future, check your clock first. It's an easy first troubleshooting point.